# Convert regexp_substr statement to SQL Server equivalent

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, csv, t-sql

I am new to converting oracle sql statement to t-sql. Can you please help me convert the following statement?

```
select regexp_substr(TO_CHAR(X.ITEM), '[^|]+', 1, level) CONCAT
from dual
connect by regexp_substr(TO_CHAR(X.ITEM), '[^|]+', 1, level) is not null
```

Comment: This seems to split a delimited string into parts. This can be done similar with a recursive query. But first check if your version of SQL Server supports `STRING_SPLIT`

Comment: What are `X` and `Y`?

Comment: @GMB It is both X sorry for that. It is part of a sored procedure but I am just confused on how I should convert that regexp_substr part

Comment: @dnoeth Yes it does

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to split a delimited list into rows, using character `|` as separator.

If you are running SQL Server 2016 or higher, you can use `string_split()` for this. Assuming that `x` is the table where `item` is stored, you would go:

```
select x.*, value
from x
cross apply string_split(item, '|')
```